# "Illegal instruction" appear when try to get PRID by mfc0 instruction on Loongson-3A R4 (MIPS64)?

Tags: c, assembly, mips, illegal-instruction

I want to get PRID in MIPS64 platform with below C code, the make phase passes and the binary is generated successfully, but `illegal instruction` appear when run the binary. What should do to solve this problem?

```
 uint32_t prid = 0;
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("mfc0 %0, $15" : "=r" (prid));
```

I expect that the PRID in the MIPS64 platform should be read successfully with the asm instruction in C programming language.

Comment: What hardware or emulator did you run the binary on?

Comment: @Peter Cordes: The binary runs on physical machine, not emulator, and the CPU used is: Loongson-3A R4.

Comment: Is that a privileged register?

Comment: @Myria You are right, the root cause is PRID is not a privileged register after I read more documents.  Instead, `asm volatile ("rdhwr ...` is available in user mode, but PRID not supported. Is there any other way to get PRID, e.g. by syscall?

Comment: @caryxu I don't know what OS you're on, or even then what the OS supports for MIPS64.  If it's Linux, you might be able to get what you need from `getauxval` or `/proc/cpuinfo` if it's CPU information.  I don't know what the `PRID` register is.